# Flutter Dependency Issue in "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java" file

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, dependencies

I add this dependency in pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

     fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
     flutter_local_notifications: ^6.0.0
     vibration: ^1.7.3
```

on the Run time  I get this file.

"GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java" file.

```
     public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
        public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
         flutterEngine.getPlugins()
           .add(newcom.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin());
         flutterEngine.getPlugins()
               .add(new io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.FlutterToastPlugin());
         flutterEngine.getPlugins()
              .add(new com.benjaminabel.vibration.VibrationPlugin());
      }
   }
```

and I got this error on run time.

[image]

Comment: try to align the dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` with `flutter:` line. i.e having the same space with `flutter:` line.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך thanks for suggestion, but I already align it. and also adjust with same space in line.

Answer (score 1):

Follows these steps:

-> Reinstall Flutter and Dart Plugin

-> make same(duplicate) project with Different Name (coz below step not working on same project)

-> Update dependencies version